# Google apps script, pass (two) 2 "variables" or "array" from code.gs to index.html / Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I need to pas 2 “variables”  or “arrays” from my *Code.gs* to my *index.html*  / javascript. The 2 “variables”  are the values of my sheet and the background color of the cells.
If I only pass 1 variable (waardes or kleuren) the function works, if I try to pass them both, I only get the last variable passes in the “return waardes , kleuren”.

// code.gs

```
function getSheetData(){
    var ss = spreadsheetApp.openById("1EpOCr_wjeYhn2YsQjRpAaUtaJNKv_4Rf81vnG59EvPA").getSheetByName("sheet");
    var waardes, kleuren;
    waardes = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
    kleuren = ss.getDataRange().getBackgrounds();

    return waardes, kleuren; 
}
```

// index.html / javascript

```
function functionShowSheet() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showValuesandColors).getSheetData();

    function showValuesandColors (waardes, kleuren) {
        alert(waardes);
        alert(waardes[0][0]);
        // do something with the  values and colors
    }
}
```

Comment: the comma operator will always return one result: the value of the last sub-expression.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 2):

As with the basic programming concept, most programming languages return only one value from the function. Read this article ["Why do most programming languages only return a single value from a function?"](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/12/why-do-most-programming-languages-only-return-a-single-value-from-a-function/)

So you cannot return multiple values in multiple variables from a function in javascript.

**What to do then?**

You can return a collection i.e an object or an array containing multiple values from a function.

```
function getSheetData(){
    var ss = spreadsheetApp.openById("1EpOCr_wjeYhn2YsQjRpAaUtaJNKv_4Rf81vnG59EvPA").getSheetByName("sheet");
    var waardes, kleuren;
    waardes = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
    kleuren = ss.getDataRange().getBackgrounds();

   return {waardes: waardes, kleuren: kleuren}; 
}
```

And then get the values in index.html

```
function showSheet(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showValuesandColors).getSheetData();
}

function showValuesandColors (myObj) {
    var waardes = myObj.waardes;
    var kleuren = myObj.kleuren;
}
```

---

You can also return an array instead of an object like this:

in code.gs

```
function getSheetData(){
    ....
    var resArr = [waardes, kleuren];
    return resArr;
}
```

in index.html

```
function showValuesandColors (myArr) {
    var waardes = myArr[0];
    var kleuren = myArr[1];
}
```